# Hashing a password and requiring it for delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to ruby on rails so I'm not sure how to implement this. I have a table full of entries that has a "password_hash" field. When a user creates a new entry, they enter a password. I want to (obviously) put a hash of that password in the "password_hash" field. Where does the hash command to do this go? In the model?

Secondly, when someone uses the "destroy" method to delete an entry, I want them to have to enter the password, and only destroy the entry if the hash of it matches the hash stored for that entry. I'm guessing this one goes in the destroy method in the controller, but I don't know how to do the checking.

Answer (score 0):

For the password hashing part take a look at this sreencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch.

In the same screencast you can see how to authenticate a user. In your case you just want to authenticate using the password.

```
class SomeModelWithPassword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :password

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create


  def correct_password?(password_try)
    password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password_try, password_salt)
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

In your destroy action you just check if it's a correct password

```
def destroy
  @model = SomeModelWithPassword.find(params[:id])
  if @model.correct_password? params[:password]
    @model.destroy
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the elements of doing what you want. You can create an attr_accessor on your model, have it automatically generate the password hash, and then use your control to check the deletes. BCrypt (http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/) will handle the hashing.

Your model:

```
require 'bcrypt'

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

Your controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

...
  def destroy
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    if @entry.password == params[:password]
      @entry.destroy
    else
      redirect_to @entry, :notice => 'You must enter a valid password to destroy an entry'
    end
  end
end
  end

end
```